# How directory permissions remain same after mv command?

Tags: permissions, directory, mv

There are two user A & B. sharing same server.
A has created a directory with permission 700 and both user and group are same i.e. user A

e.g.

```
drwx --- --- A A temp_dir/
```

Now user B has permission to access A's files. What B did is, he moved this "temp_dir/"  to his home directory.

Now this moved directory has the same permission before i.e. 700 with user and group is A.
When B is trying to access the files from this directory he is not able to do it.
He is not able to change the permission neither he has sudo/root user permission.

How B can access this directory?

Comment: "B has permission to access A's files" does that imply they are in the same group?

Answer (score 1):

> How B can access this directory?

Well, the directory belongs to A, and A did not grant any permissions on this directory to B. Therefore B cannot access the directory. It's that simple.

If A (or root) wants to grant permissions to B then they should do so with `chmod` (or `chown` if root does it).

Comment: Actually B has the permission to access the parent directory of "remp_dir/" 
that's why he is able to move this directory to his home directory.

Comment: Correct, that's why he is able to move it. But that does not change the fact that he still does not have any permissions to it after moving it.

Comment: Yes, but if he moved the directory from A's home directory, now it is a part of B's directory, B should have control over it, isn't it?

Comment: Why should that be? You said yourself, the permissions of that directory are `rwx------` and the owner is A. So A is the only user (other than root, of course) who can access the directory.